# Is Bootstrap 2.3.2 compatible with jQuery 1.9?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

We're running it with 1.8 with no problems, but is it supported for 1.9?

Comment: The Bootstrap guys **really** make it hard to find this sort of information. My guess is yes, it's fine with 1.9. There's a mention of it here - http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2013/02/07/bootstrap-2-3-released/

Comment: Try and see? I appreciate this is a valid concern but polling for anecdotal evidence isn't really on-topic I'd say.

Comment: It's not whether it works that I'm asking- it's whether it's supported.

Comment: For future reference, check the bower.json file https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v2.3.2/bower.json. In this case, yes it is, until jQuery 2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is compatible.

They are used in below site and it works perfectly.

http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0JLR295

[image]